# Django SessionWizardView jumps back to the first step after page is reloaded

Tags: django, django-forms, django-formwizard

I am working with a `SessionWizardView` which is managing two forms. When I reload the page at the last step for instance I am back at the first step and have to type in all the fields again.

Is this the intended behaviour? If so, is it possible to get back to step I was at before I reloaded the page? Of course all the fields should be filled out accordingly.

```
class ManufacturingCalculatorWizard(SessionWizardView):
  def get_template_names(self):
    TEMPLATES = {
        "blueprint": "manufacturing/forms/select_blueprint.haml",
        "calculator": "manufacturing/forms/calculator.haml"
    }

    return [TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]

  def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
    form_data = [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]
    rcontext = RequestContext(self.request, { 'data' : calculate_manufacturing_job(form_data) })
    return render_to_response('manufacturing/forms/result.haml', rcontext)
```

Comment: When you reload, do you post data as well?

Comment: Browser is asking if I want to re-send the form. So yes, it seems like I am sending post data again.

Comment: I don't see that behavior in my code. You may want to post wizard view code, template code.

Comment: @Rohan I added the code for the Wizard.

Comment: I have a suspicion. It's the `done` method. I have three steps. First step = form, second step = form and third step is the result page returned by the `done` method. Reloading first and second step works but reloading the result page goes wrong. So `FormWizardView` itself is working. Now the question is: How can I reload the result page and basically trigger the `done` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page rendered after `done` method is not part of wizard, so when you reload it, django will try to redirect to first page as new session of wizard.

If you want to add last step as something like preview and confirmation page, you can add a new step with dummy form and show appropriate data using the template. To get data from previous steps you can make use of [get_context_data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views.WizardView.get_context_data) method of view, to build context with cleaned data of previous forms.